# View war file as folder - JBOSS

Tags: jboss7.x, web-deployment

My old company using glassfish, when I deployed I can view deployed as folder, view inside with .xhtml and .class file

Ex: if I need hot fix something, I just access to folder that glassfish deploy and change something.

How can I do it JBoss, when deploy success just have a *.war, I cannot view inside.

Comment: How are you deploying your application and what version of JBoss AS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Netbeans, Maven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you are publishing you war.

If you are using Eclipse to deploy WAR follow these steps.

1. Goto server view
2. Double Click on server
3. Goto Deployment tab
4. Uncheck "Deploy projects as compressed archives"

Publish it again.